# ESXI 6.0 system disk boot failure

Tags: linux, vmware-esxi, boot

My Poweredge 2950 running esxi 6.0 has worked for a long time. Running raid5 on 4 2TB disks. And one 1TB for system and VM. First I notised that I could't open console on my VM's. After a reboot some VM's did not start. Datastore1 (1TB system disk) was not online. (dont know how esxi could start without that disk, but have read that it can run only on RAM if the disk failes.) I could not connect to any VM's, even if thay was running. So I desided that I should shut it down and try to figure out why. Under boot I get that there is foreign configuration on my raid card Perc5i. When i go in there, I can only find my 2TB disks. And if I continue the boot I get PXE-E61: Media test failure, check cable PXE-MOF: Exiting Broadcom PXE ROM.

And there it freeze. On my raid5 I got all my private files, documents, pictures and videos. Wedding plans and everything. Is there a way to get this files out ? Or even get esxi to boot ?

Comment: 1) What did Dell support say? 2) Better check your backups. 3) Did you have alerting set up for disk failures? You may have had two drive fail, in which case your data is likely gone.

Comment: So the single 1TB is where ESXi is installed and also where the VM storage is? Why didn't you put the VM storage on the RAID5 array?

Comment: 1: I dont have any Dell support service. 2: dont have any backup of that disk :( 3: I did not set this up.. Think i need one now.. :)

Answer (score 0):

If the 1TB disk is SATA, as it seem in a JBOD's mode as how I read your question, I would extract it from the server to check it offline from another computer to try a data extraction if the disk is starting to be corrupt.

If it's valuable to you, be aware you can get professional's service to extract the disk data for a price, and usually they offer a estimate. (as they read each platen from the HDD to extract the data) Personally I seen price range from 750$ to 2000$ for a hard extraction of the data, and they gave back the data on a usb disk,